# Memory usage and space disk on Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, performance, monitoring

How can I monitor

- Memory Usage: 33/512MB (6%)
- Disk usage: 4.2/20GB (23%)
- CPU Load: 0.01

on a Solaris 11 System? I want to make a script to monitor my desktop resources.

Comment: Do any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please [consider accepting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have one system then SAR is the a good alternative out of the box.
If you have multiple system you might want to evaluate other choices as well besides SAR.

[Xymon](http://xymon.sourceforge.net/) and [dimSTAT](http://dimitrik.free.fr/) are two of them that I use and recommend.
dimSTAT is specially good for Solaris as it was developed with Solaris in mind by a Sun Engineer.
Xymon is multipurpose and highly customizable.

Now if you want to use your own scripting then there are several possibilites and you should use the one that suits you best. examples inline: `echo "::memstat"|mdb -k`

```
root@solsrv01:~# echo "::memstat" |mdb -k
Page Summary                 Pages             Bytes  %Tot
----------------- ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                      114567            447.5M   11%
ZFS Metadata                  7312             28.5M    1%
ZFS File Data                72180            281.9M    7%
Anon                         36257            141.6M    3%
Exec and libs                 1559              6.0M    0%
Page cache                    6286             24.5M    1%
Free (cachelist)              8973             35.0M    1%
Free (freelist)             784053              2.9G   75%
Total                      1048463              3.9G
```

you will need to look at the right line and get the desired values.
for cpu load you can use uptime, prstat or even kstat.

```
root@solsrv01:~# uptime
 11:35pm  up 12 min(s),  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.29, 0.30

root@solsrv01:~# prstat -c 1 1
Please wait...
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE   PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP
     5 root        0K    0K sleep    99  -20   0:00:01 0.1% zpool-rpool/147
   996 root       11M 3064K cpu0     49    0   0:00:00 0.1% prstat/1
   957 root       21M 7064K sleep    59    0   0:00:01 0.1% sshd/1
   958 root       11M 3188K sleep    49    0   0:00:00 0.0% bash/1
   489 root     3964K 2116K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% hald-addon-acpi/1
   480 root     8204K 6312K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% hald/4
    68 netadm   5320K 3360K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% ipmgmtd/6
    86 root     4044K 2284K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% svc.periodicd/4
   547 root       15M 3040K sleep    59    0   0:01:03 0.0% ldap_cachemgr/8
   360 root       10M 2464K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% picld/4
    45 netadm     11M 2288K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% ibmgmtd/4
    42 netcfg   3748K 2588K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% netcfgd/4
    15 root       20M   19M sleep    59    0   0:00:46 0.0% svc.configd/31
    13 root       53M   33M sleep    59    0   0:00:13 0.0% svc.startd/15
   185 root       18M 3740K sleep    59    0   0:00:00 0.0% rad/4
Total: 62 processes, 397 lwps, load averages: 0.02, 0.25, 0.29

root@solsrv01:~# kstat -p 'unix:0:system_misc:avenrun*'|awk '{print $1"\t"$2/256}'
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_15min        0.269531
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_1min 0.0195312
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_5min 0.203125
```

For disk usage:

```
root@solsrv01:~# df -h
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/solaris      19G   2.8G        13G    18%    /
/devices                 0K     0K         0K     0%    /devices
/dev                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev
ctfs                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   3.9G   1.6M       3.9G     1%    /system/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                        16G   2.8G        13G    18%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev/fd
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var
                        19G   221M        13G     2%    /var
swap                   3.9G     4K       3.9G     1%    /tmp
rpool/VARSHARE          19G   2.4M        13G     1%    /var/share
rpool/export            19G    32K        13G     1%    /export
rpool/export/home       19G    38K        13G     1%    /export/home
rpool                   19G   4.5M        13G     1%    /rpool
rpool/VARSHARE/zones    19G    31K        13G     1%    /system/zones
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg      19G    32K        13G     1%    /var/share/pkg
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg/repositories
                        19G    31K        13G     1%    /var/share/pkg/repositories
root@solsrv01:~# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool  19.6G  6.08G  13.5G  30%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Comment: Many Thansk dude!.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sar`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/sar-1.html#scrolltoc).

> **sar**
>
> - system activity reporter

Also, read [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/enudq.html#scrolltoc)

> **Monitoring System Activities (sar)**
>
> Use the sar command to perform the following tasks:
>
> - Organize and view data about system activity.
> - Access system activity data on a special request basis.
> - Generate automatic reports to measure and monitor system performance, as well as special request reports to pinpoint specific
>     performance problems. For information about how to set up the sar
>     command to run on your system, as well as a description of these
>     tools, see Collecting System Activity Data Automatically (sar).
>
> For a detailed description of this command, see the sar(1) man page.

and [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/spconcepts-60676.html).

> **Collecting System Activity Data Automatically (sar)**
>
> Three commands are involved in the automatic collection of system
>   activity data: sadc, sa1, and sa2.
>
> ...