# sun solaris 11.2 sysstat

Tags: solaris, sysstat

I've sun solaris 11.2 and I want to install and use sysstat and use it the way I use it on linux-ubuntu to monitor some activities and run cpu and memory checks for certain time intervals.

I was looking in the internet i couldn't find sysstat for solaris, so could you please help me how to install on solaris if exists

if not, is there any other simple command or utility that I can use to monitor the cpu and memory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266798/memory-usage-and-space-disk-on-solaris-11

Answer (score 3):

Many tools are available on Solaris 11.2 by default like:

```
vmstat
prstat
iostat
mpstat
```

You can also use `top`, I don't remember if it is installed by default, but the package is called: `pkg:/diagnostic/top`

EDIT:

To enable `sar` you can install the package `pkg:/system/accounting/legacy-accounting` and configure the `crontab` for the `sys` account:

```
crontab -l sys
#ident  "%Z%%M% %I%     %E% SMI"        /* SVr4.0 1.2   */
#
# The sys crontab should be used to do performance collection. See cron
# and performance manual pages for details on startup.
#
 0 * * * 0-6 /usr/lib/sa/sa1
 20,40 8-17 * * 1-5 /usr/lib/sa/sa1
 5 18 * * 1-5 /usr/lib/sa/sa2 -s 8:00 -e 18:01 -i 1200 -A
```

Data is stored in `/var/adm/sa`

Comment: These seem great but i want to run monitoring for intervals and store to txt later on to analyze the difference. Meaning I want to enable auditing and compare memory and cpu results before and after enabling the auditing on solaris.
In ubuntu i would be using sar configured to run every 5 minutes intervals

Comment: @N.J, Just saw your comment. the system accounting and reporting utility is also available for Solaris, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment to @Lambert's answer, what you are looking for is called GUDS. This tool that is available for customer with support and it will gather all the stats that you specify for a time period. You can define the interval, for how long and start and stop time.

Otherwise, you need to do it manually with the tools Lambert mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

sysstat is just a collation of tools, most of which can be found on Solaris, as well as other UNIX OSes.

An older tool that did what you want was called canary.  You could also look into using Nagios.  I've seen multiple blogs and docs showing how to build Nagios for Solaris 11.  I think there's even an official Oracle doc showing how to build it and make it a deployable IPS package.

If you are a larger shop with a support contract, you may also want to consider using Ops Center.